# How to configure an Element-collection to map an existing DB table in JPA orm.xml configuration?

Tags: hibernate, orm, collections, mapping, jpa-2.0

I have migrated an app from a full-Hibernate featured one to a JPA/Hibernate based-one and I have a problem with my JPA mapping.

We have managed to use orm.xml to map our entities. Everything was working fine until I have had to deal with an Element-collection.
Actually, I have an entity called **User** which has an embedded map (Map collection called **preferences**). So we have something like that :

```
public class User {
        private Long id;
        private Map<String, String> preferences;
}
```

In our full-hibernate version, a PREFERENCE(ID, name, value) table gets generated. But when we tried to migrate it to JPA, we used the following mapping :

```
<element-collection name="preferences" target-class="java.lang.String" fetch="LAZY">
       <map-key-class class="java.lang.String" />
       <map-key-column name="[name]" />
       <column name="[value]" />
       <collection-table name="PREFERENCE">
           <join-column name="ID" />
       </collection-table>
</element-collection>
```

and a new **User_Preferences** table gets generated. Even though I have specified a **name='PREFERENCES'** attribute in the xml configuration, **I can't get the element-collection to point to the existing table PREFERENCES**.

Have you ever experienced this situation ?
Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks a lot guyz,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like a bug. I cannot point anything wrong with your mappings and I tried it with EclipseLink 2.3.0 and such a mapping created table named PREFERENCE. Also tried with Hibernate 3.5.6, and name of table is USER_PREFERENCES as you said.

Looks like they simply discard name for collection-table. But same with annotations works fine:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class)
@MapKeyClass(java.lang.String.class)
@MapKeyColumn(name="name")
@CollectionTable(name = "PREFERENCE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="ID"))
@Column(name="value")
```

Comment: It's really weird and since I guess this kind of mapping is uncommon, nobody has stumbled upon it ...
I have been looking around for at least half a day but didn't find out how to deal with that ...

Comment: Is annotating field option for you?

Comment: If annotation solves the problem, I would get into it directly. But for now all of the mapping is made with xml. Actually I hate this f$*$*ng xml configuration and I would have chosen annotations instead but my boss didn't want to so ...

Comment: > you know what ? I'm going to use annotations just to see the results ...Thanks a lot

Comment: It will solve your problem, assuming that there is no difference in implementation for this between Hibernate versions. Just in case, don't forget to remove metadata-complete from persistence.xml if you have it.

Comment: is this automatically taken into account by JPA (I mean the annotations) ? or do I have to set some configuration option in the JPA conf file for it to scan my persistent classes ?

Thx ;-)

Comment: Depends about setup, they are found quite many ways: 1) if they are in same jar where persistence.xml then they are kind of found automatically based to convention 2) if they are listed in persistence.xml, 3) can pack to separate jar and reference that with <jar-file> in persistence.xml. etc. Of course you can totally mix both annotations xml configuration, even for same entity.

Comment: it rocks :-) no additional config, I have just added the annotations and it worked ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this structure:

```
Set<Preference> preferences;
```

then transform your set to a map computationaly.

Comment: well the problem, is that I have already an existing table created by an earlier version of the app (which was a full-hibernate-backed one), so I need to take into account the existing database and  ensure that the new version doesn't change its structure (at least not a lot)...

Comment: what I am saying is that you could add a new entity called Preference which would map direct on your PREFERENCE table. Then use a many-to-one relation, in the fashion I have shown above. That way each user will have many Preference entities assosiated with it.